# How to add top and bottom frame to a video using ffmpeg and imagemagick

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, video-processing, imagemagick-convert, video-editing

I'm trying to add a top and bottom section to a video like we do for image memes. I'm using ffmpeg and imagemagick but there is no inbuilt option to do this task. Let's say i have a video and I need to add the caption like this to the whole video. How can i achieve this?

[image]

Comment: What is the format of your video? Do you mean you want to overlay the white writing on top of each frame - you don't want to increase the height of the frame.

Comment: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, i want to add a white rectangle on top of each frame and write a text on it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what I can tell something like this is what you're looking for:

[image]

Using [pad](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) and [drawtext](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext). In this example *pad* adds 50 pixels to the top and 50 pixels to the bottom, then two *drawtext* instances place each line.

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"[0:v]pad=iw:ih+100:0:(oh-ih)/2:color=white, \
 drawtext=text='ONE DOES NOT SIMPLY':fontfile=/path/to/impact.ttf:fontsize=24:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(50-th)/2, \
 drawtext=text='STOP ME FROM FILTERING':fontfile=/path/to/impact.ttf:fontsize=24:x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-25-(th/2)" \
output
```

Comment: Hi @LordNeckbeard, 
1. "color = white" , how can we change the color, can we pass "#somevalue". 
2. "fontfile=/path/to/impact.ttf" is that a built-in ttf file or we are supposed to give some path from assets file as per android.

Comment: @BSTKaal As for `color` in `pad`, you can use [these color names](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Color). As for `fontfile` you need to provide the path to the font that you want to use. If your `ffmpeg` build was compiled with `--enable-libfontconfig`, then you can just supply the name as shown in the [fontconfig example](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-39) (3rd from bottom). Sorry, I know nothing of Android.

Comment: the command is running, but the output video has only one frame, i.e. the length of video is even less than a sec...

Comment: Thank you so much @LordNechbeard, I fixed the issue removing `-vframes 1`.